# Problems with transparency in EEVEE

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, transparency

Help me please with EEVEE.

Blend-file:

https://mega.nz/file/eH5yRahY#4v3JtwS1N7OY_hAKdnPP6oDQZQVWk7F36D7fuzkCvqo

There is an empty capsule inside, the door of which is transparent. There are two problems with them:

[image]

1. The wall behind Susanna becomes transparent along the contours of Susanna herself (If the suzanne is removed, the walls cease to be transparent).
2. Suzanne's image stretches as if the capsule was flooded with water. It should not stretch (This can be checked by switching to Cycles)

Сhanges that I made in the program:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *Eevee* is no Raytracing Engine like *Cycles*, it doesn't really take the glass thickness into account for the refractions. So in order to make it work as if the glass had some thickness to it and is not just a giant block of glass enclosing Suzanne, in the *Material Properties* you have to set the *Refraction Depth* to some reasonable value above 0. In my example I've set it to 0.1 m (still very thick for a glass plane) and it already looks a lot better... and I guess this helps with other issues as well.

[image: eevee refraction]